# firebase realtime database updating value twice

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set a bool value in real time database in flutter but it changes the value twice. first its set the value to false from true then it immediately change it to true again.

```
Future<void> changeTurnkey1(String roomCode, String key1) async {
var codeRef = _codeRef(roomCode);
await codeRef.child(playersKey).child(key1).get().then((value) async {
final Map snapshotMap = value.value;
bool val = snapshotMap[canPlay];
if (val) {
  await codeRef.child(playersKey).child(key1).update({
    canPlay: false,
  });
} else {
  codeRef.child(playersKey).child(key1).update({
    canPlay: true,
  });
}
});
}
```

Comment: "first its set the value to false from true then it immediately change it to true again." I'm not sure I understand what happens in your app. Can you edit your question to describe (or better yet: show) how you've observed this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're using both `async/await` and `.then()`... This would definitely have undesired effects.

Try just using `async/await` like this:

```
Future<void> changeTurnkey1(String roomCode, String key1) async {
var codeRef = _codeRef(roomCode);
var value = await codeRef.child(playersKey).child(key1).get()
final Map snapshotMap = value.value;
bool val = snapshotMap[canPlay];
if (val) {
  await codeRef.child(playersKey).child(key1).update({
    canPlay: false,
  });
} else {
  codeRef.child(playersKey).child(key1).update({
    canPlay: true,
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
Finally found out that our old server program(nodejs docker) forgot to stop.